# How to handle concurrent inserts in jpa

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I currently have multiple messages arriving in the very same second. They have the following attributes:

1. ParentKey
2. Description
3. Amount

The logic is as follows:

1. Find Parent where key = ParentKey

   a) If parent does not exist, insert parent with key = ParentKey
2. Insert child with (id, parent_key, description, amount)

Now the problem is that in parallel processing I either get an exception with isolation level SERIALIZE (is this correct one?) or a  UniqueConstraintViolation for the parent.

If I had no unique constraint on key but just a serial id I would end up with multiple entries.

Is there any way to prevent this? Or any retry mechanism? I just want one insert for this id.

Comment: sorry for not being helpful there mate :

Comment: @aran Your solution would at least work if we stay with a single worker at all times. Better than nothing I guess. Don't think I'll get another answer, so feel free to post it

Comment: If you use reader writer lock, it may solve the problem. It means only one will write but others can read.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation.  I my case, I created another ejb with Transaction Attribute set to REQUIRES_NEW and perform the insertions there then in the caller ejb catch the potential exception.  Then in the catch block and make another call to the ejb that does the insertions.

This approach may not work in all cases if you want the inserts be a part of the same transaction as the other database update activities.

Comment: If you want the insert to be a part of the same transaction consider the retry in the Web layer.

In your Restful API receiver or servlet call your EJB with a try catch block that does all the database DML operations catch exception and retry there.  The Restful API/servlet should not be a part of a transaction and only initiates one within your ejb.

Comment: If you are using JPA Entity Manager you may also use lock modes as described in https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/locking-and-concurrency-in-java-persistence-20.  To enable lock mode you also need to have a "version" column to store entity version numbers.